# "admin/content" filters not available anymore

Tags: 8

In the Content page (/admin/content), in Drupal 7 there was a feature allowing to filter by content type, status or language:

> [image: screenshot]

It doesn't seem to be available anymore in Drupal 8.

> [image: screenshot]

Someone know if there is a module recreating this feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need just to install the Views module that is part of Drupal core. Once you install it, that page appears as the following, which is how I see it in my site.

> [image: screenshot]

If I uninstall the Views module, that page appears like the following.

> [image: screenshot]

Now that the Views module is in core, there are many pages that have been converted into views. As you see from the first screenshot, there is a new *Files* tab which is a view.

If you don't see the Views module listed between the modules, download again Drupal, because that means the archive used for the installation is missing some Drupal files, or they have not been correctly copied.

Answer (score 5):

You might have deleted the Content view by mistake. To re-import it, setup a new or another Drupal 8 site. In the new site goto `Configuration > Configuration synchronization > Export Tab > Single Item`, `Configuration type: View`, `Configuration name: Content (content)`. And then copy the contents of the "Here is your configuration". In your original site goto `Configuration > Configuration synchronization > Import tab > Single item`, `Configuration type: View` and paste into "Paste your configuration here" and press Import.

Comment: Or Drupal might have deleted the Content view. When you add an extra field to the view and then remove the field from the content type, Drupal deletes the view (and any other views that use this field) along. This might seem logical from a technical perspective but is crap from a user perspective.

Comment: This works for me. Oddly, checking the problem site's config, I could find the Content (content), but I imported it anyway from stage site, and filter popped back on the content overview page. I didn't run a diff prior to import but likely something was different since I'd been deleting the meta field prior to this happening.

Comment: Drupal had removed my views.view.content.yml after I uninstalled a module.

Answer (score 1):

Goto Configuration > Configuration synchronization > Import tab > Single item, Configuration type: View and paste into the code below into "Paste your configuration here" and press Import.

```
uuid: 4095ee08-6690-4d23-a401-fca549d2e42a
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  module:
    - node
    - user
_core:
  default_config_hash: tS8PbpJX90aRFC3-UTgXzdqkq7_2frk2pz4TMijEebM
id: content
label: Content
module: node
description: 'Find and manage content.'
tag: default
base_table: node_field_data
base_field: nid
core: 8.x
display:
  default:
    display_options:
      access:
        type: perm
        options:
          perm: 'access content overview'
      cache:
        type: tag
      query:
        type: views_query
      exposed_form:
        type: basic
        options:
          submit_button: Filter
          reset_button: true
          reset_button_label: Reset
          exposed_sorts_label: 'Sort by'
          expose_sort_order: true
          sort_asc_label: Asc
          sort_desc_label: Desc
      pager:
        type: full
        options:
          items_per_page: 50
          tags:
            previous: '‹ Previous'
            next: 'Next ›'
            first: '« First'
            last: 'Last »'
      style:
        type: table
        options:
          grouping: {  }
          row_class: ''
          default_row_class: true
          override: true
          sticky: true
          caption: ''
          summary: ''
          description: ''
          columns:
            node_bulk_form: node_bulk_form
            title: title
            type: type
            name: name
            status: status
            changed: changed
            edit_node: edit_node
            delete_node: delete_node
            dropbutton: dropbutton
            timestamp: title
          info:
            node_bulk_form:
              align: ''
              separator: ''
              empty_column: false
              responsive: ''
            title:
              sortable: true
              default_sort_order: asc
              align: ''
              separator: ''
              empty_column: false
              responsive: ''
            type:
              sortable: true
              default_sort_order: asc
              align: ''
              separator: ''
              empty_column: false
              responsive: ''
            name:
              sortable: false
              default_sort_order: asc
              align: ''
              separator: ''
              empty_column: false
              responsive: priority-low
            status:
              sortable: true
              default_sort_order: asc
              align: ''
              separator: ''
              empty_column: false
              responsive: ''
            changed:
              sortable: true
              default_sort_order: desc
              align: ''
              separator: ''
              empty_column: false
              responsive: priority-low
            edit_node:
              sortable: false
              default_sort_order: asc
              align: ''
              separator: ''
              empty_column: false
              responsive: ''
            delete_node:
              sortable: false
              default_sort_order: asc
              align: ''
              separator: ''
              empty_column: false
              responsive: ''
            dropbutton:
              sortable: false
              default_sort_order: asc
              align: ''
              separator: ''
              empty_column: false
              responsive: ''
            timestamp:
              sortable: false
              default_sort_order: asc
              align: ''
              separator: ''
              empty_column: false
              responsive: ''
          default: changed
          empty_table: true
      row:
        type: fields
      fields:
        node_bulk_form:
          id: node_bulk_form
          table: node
          field: node_bulk_form
          label: ''
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
          element_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          plugin_id: node_bulk_form
          entity_type: node
        title:
          id: title
          table: node_field_data
          field: title
          label: Title
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
          element_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: title
          type: string
          settings:
            link_to_entity: true
          plugin_id: field
        type:
          id: type
          table: node_field_data
          field: type
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: 'Content type'
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: true
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: target_id
          type: entity_reference_label
          settings:
            link: false
          group_column: target_id
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: type
          plugin_id: field
        name:
          id: name
          table: users_field_data
          field: name
          relationship: uid
          label: Author
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
          element_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          plugin_id: field
          type: user_name
          entity_type: user
          entity_field: name
        status:
          id: status
          table: node_field_data
          field: status
          label: Status
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
          element_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          type: boolean
          settings:
            format: custom
            format_custom_true: Published
            format_custom_false: Unpublished
          plugin_id: field
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: status
        changed:
          id: changed
          table: node_field_data
          field: changed
          label: Updated
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
          element_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          type: timestamp
          settings:
            date_format: short
            custom_date_format: ''
            timezone: ''
          plugin_id: field
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: changed
        operations:
          id: operations
          table: node
          field: operations
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: Operations
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: true
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          destination: true
          plugin_id: entity_operations
      filters:
        title:
          id: title
          table: node_field_data
          field: title
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          operator: contains
          value: ''
          group: 1
          exposed: true
          expose:
            operator_id: title_op
            label: Title
            description: ''
            use_operator: false
            operator: title_op
            identifier: title
            required: false
            remember: false
            multiple: false
            remember_roles:
              authenticated: authenticated
              anonymous: '0'
              administrator: '0'
          is_grouped: false
          group_info:
            label: ''
            description: ''
            identifier: ''
            optional: true
            widget: select
            multiple: false
            remember: false
            default_group: All
            default_group_multiple: {  }
            group_items: {  }
          plugin_id: string
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: title
        type:
          id: type
          table: node_field_data
          field: type
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          operator: in
          value: {  }
          group: 1
          exposed: true
          expose:
            operator_id: type_op
            label: 'Content type'
            description: ''
            use_operator: false
            operator: type_op
            identifier: type
            required: false
            remember: false
            multiple: false
            remember_roles:
              authenticated: authenticated
              anonymous: '0'
              administrator: '0'
            reduce: false
          is_grouped: false
          group_info:
            label: ''
            description: ''
            identifier: ''
            optional: true
            widget: select
            multiple: false
            remember: false
            default_group: All
            default_group_multiple: {  }
            group_items: {  }
          plugin_id: bundle
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: type
        status:
          id: status
          table: node_field_data
          field: status
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          operator: '='
          value: '1'
          group: 1
          exposed: true
          expose:
            operator_id: ''
            label: Status
            description: ''
            use_operator: false
            operator: status_op
            identifier: status
            required: false
            remember: false
            multiple: false
            remember_roles:
              authenticated: authenticated
          is_grouped: true
          group_info:
            label: 'Published status'
            description: ''
            identifier: status
            optional: true
            widget: select
            multiple: false
            remember: false
            default_group: All
            default_group_multiple: {  }
            group_items:
              1:
                title: Published
                operator: '='
                value: '1'
              2:
                title: Unpublished
                operator: '='
                value: '0'
          plugin_id: boolean
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: status
        langcode:
          id: langcode
          table: node_field_data
          field: langcode
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          operator: in
          value: {  }
          group: 1
          exposed: true
          expose:
            operator_id: langcode_op
            label: Language
            description: ''
            use_operator: false
            operator: langcode_op
            identifier: langcode
            required: false
            remember: false
            multiple: false
            remember_roles:
              authenticated: authenticated
              anonymous: '0'
              administrator: '0'
            reduce: false
          is_grouped: false
          group_info:
            label: ''
            description: ''
            identifier: ''
            optional: true
            widget: select
            multiple: false
            remember: false
            default_group: All
            default_group_multiple: {  }
            group_items: {  }
          plugin_id: language
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: langcode
        status_extra:
          id: status_extra
          table: node_field_data
          field: status_extra
          operator: '='
          value: false
          plugin_id: node_status
          group: 1
          entity_type: node
      sorts: {  }
      title: Content
      empty:
        area_text_custom:
          id: area_text_custom
          table: views
          field: area_text_custom
          empty: true
          content: 'No content available.'
          plugin_id: text_custom
      arguments: {  }
      relationships:
        uid:
          id: uid
          table: node_field_data
          field: uid
          admin_label: author
          required: true
          plugin_id: standard
      show_admin_links: false
      filter_groups:
        operator: AND
        groups:
          1: AND
      display_extenders: {  }
    display_plugin: default
    display_title: Master
    id: default
    position: 0
    cache_metadata:
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - url
        - url.query_args
        - user
        - 'user.node_grants:view'
        - user.permissions
      max-age: 0
      tags: {  }
  page_1:
    display_options:
      path: admin/content/node
      menu:
        type: 'default tab'
        title: Content
        description: ''
        menu_name: admin
        weight: -10
        context: ''
      tab_options:
        type: normal
        title: Content
        description: 'Find and manage content'
        menu_name: admin
        weight: -10
      display_extenders: {  }
    display_plugin: page
    display_title: Page
    id: page_1
    position: 1
    cache_metadata:
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - url
        - url.query_args
        - user
        - 'user.node_grants:view'
        - user.permissions
      max-age: 0
      tags: {  }
```

Comment: Confirmed this config still valid in 8.9.16.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt have the synch option, so I just uninstalled views and re-installed it. That recreated the missing views that I lost somehow.